# Missing annotation processing in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I'm using Android Studio 2.2.3 and build tools 24.0.2.

Several of the libraries, including Butterknife use annotations in build.gradle for the app I'm trying to compile. On the first I get this error:

Gradle sync failed: Could not find method annotationProcessor() for arguments [com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0]

At the AS start up window I've edited the preferences and ticked Annotation Processing. I cleared the caches and restarted Android. Still getting that error.

App level build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
        classpath 'com.github.triplet.gradle:play-publisher:1.1.4'
        //noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '3.1'
    distributionUrl = distributionUrl.replace("bin", "all")
}
```

Mod level build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: '../config/quality/quality.gradle'
apply plugin: 'com.github.triplet.play'
//TODO uncomment line below after adding fabric api secret and key to fabric.properties
//apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion '24.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.murphysw.rosie'
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        testInstrumentationRunner "${applicationId}.runner.RxAndroidJUnitRunner"
        versionCode 1000
        // Major -> Millions, Minor -> Thousands, Bugfix -> Hundreds. E.g 1.3.72 == 1,003,072
        versionName '0.1.0'
    }
    signingConfigs {
        // You must set up an environment var before release signing
        // Run: export APP_KEY={password}
        // TODO Add your release keystore in /keystore folder
        release {
            storeFile file('keystore/release.keystore')
            keyAlias 'alias'
            storePassword "$System.env.APP_KEY"
            keyPassword "$System.env.APP_KEY"
        }

        debug {
            storeFile file('keystore/debug.keystore')
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            storePassword 'android'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release

            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

            ext.betaDistributionReleaseNotesFilePath =
                    file('../crashlytics_release_notes.txt').absolutePath
        }

        debug {
            versionNameSuffix " Debug"
            debuggable true
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        def commonTestDir = 'src/commonTest/java'
        test {
            java.srcDir commonTestDir
        }
        androidTest {
            java.srcDir commonTestDir
        }
    }
    //Needed because of this https://github.com/square/okio/issues/58
    lintOptions {
        warning 'InvalidPackage'
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

play {
    serviceAccountEmail = 'your-service-account-email'
    pk12File = file('key.p12')
    // By default publishes to Alpha channel
    track = 'alpha'
}

dependencies {
    final PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION = '9.6.1'
//    final SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION = '25.0.1'
    final SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION = '24.0.2'
    final RETROFIT_VERSION = '2.1.0'
    final DAGGER_VERSION = '2.5'
    final DEXMAKER_VERSION = '1.4'
    final HAMCREST_VERSION = '1.3'
    final ESPRESSO_VERSION = '2.2.1'
    final RUNNER_VERSION = '0.4'
    final BUTTERKNIFE_VERSION = '8.4.0'
    final AUTO_VALUE_VERSION = '1.3'
    final AUTO_VALUE_GSON_VERSION = '0.4.2'
    def daggerCompiler = "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$DAGGER_VERSION"
    def jUnit = "junit:junit:4.12"
    def mockito = "org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19"
    // App Dependencies
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:$PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION"
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION"
    compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION"
    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION"
    compile "com.android.support:support-annotations:$SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION"
    compile('com.squareup.sqlbrite:sqlbrite:0.8.0')
    {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    }
    compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$RETROFIT_VERSION"
    compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$RETROFIT_VERSION"
    compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:$RETROFIT_VERSION"
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.6'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.7@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.1.2'
    compile "com.jakewharton:butterknife:$BUTTERKNIFE_VERSION" annotationProcessor "com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:$BUTTERKNIFE_VERSION"
    // Replace provided dependency below with official AutoValue once this issue is fixed

    // https://github.com/google/auto/issues/268
    provided "com.jakewharton.auto.value:auto-value-annotations:$AUTO_VALUE_VERSION" provided "com.ryanharter.auto.value:auto-value-gson:$AUTO_VALUE_GSON_VERSION" annotationProcessor "com.google.auto.value:auto-value:$AUTO_VALUE_VERSION" annotationProcessor 'com.ryanharter.auto.value:auto-value-parcel:0.2.4-rc2'
    annotationProcessor "com.ryanharter.auto.value:auto-value-gson:$AUTO_VALUE_GSON_VERSION" annotationProcessor 'com.squareup:javapoet:1.7.0'
    // https://github.com/rharter/auto-value-parcel/issues/64
    compile "com.google.dagger:dagger:$DAGGER_VERSION" provided 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'
    //Required by Dagger2
    annotationProcessor daggerCompiler testAnnotationProcessor daggerCompiler androidTestAnnotationProcessor daggerCompiler
    // Instrumentation test dependencies
    androidTestCompile jUnit
    androidTestCompile mockito
    androidTestCompile "com.android.support:support-annotations:$SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION"
    androidTestCompile("com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:$ESPRESSO_VERSION")
    {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'recyclerview-v7'
    }
    androidTestCompile "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:$ESPRESSO_VERSION"
    androidTestCompile "com.android.support.test:runner:$RUNNER_VERSION"
    androidTestCompile "com.android.support.test:rules:$RUNNER_VERSION"
    androidTestCompile "com.crittercism.dexmaker:dexmaker:$DEXMAKER_VERSION"
    androidTestCompile "com.crittercism.dexmaker:dexmaker-dx:$DEXMAKER_VERSION"
    androidTestCompile "com.crittercism.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:$DEXMAKER_VERSION"
    // Unit tests dependencies
    testCompile jUnit testCompile mockito testCompile "org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:$HAMCREST_VERSION" testCompile "org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:$HAMCREST_VERSION" testCompile "org.hamcrest:hamcrest-integration:$HAMCREST_VERSION" testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.1'
}

// Log out test results to console
tasks.matching {it instanceof Test}.all {
    testLogging.events = ["failed", "passed", "skipped"]
}
```

Comment: What is the gradle version in build.gradle set to? Is it > 2.2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The butterknife page asks to include this line :

```
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'
```

Did you include that in your app level gradle?

Comment: I'm using a template project from a company called Ribot. It's widely used so I suspect the problem is with my set up of Android Studio. That line does seem to be included. AS does not seem to have an annotation processor defined. It looks like this feature was previously included by plug-in and now is supposed to be baked in. Thanks!

Comment: It turned out the Ribot template was missing a couple of lines and the build.gradle files needed some additional linefeeds between tasks. Follow the instructions for Butterknife installation here: https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife to enable annotation processing for that library.